# android: how to obtain a user trusted private key from app

Tags: android, sdk, keystore, private-key

i was wondering if there's any chance to read programmatically the private key from android's `keystore/keychain` (installed by user via *Settings–security–install from SD card*) by app itself?

the purpose is to sign a data by this key to serve it to server afterwards.

Comment: "i was wondering if there's any chance to read programmatically the private key from android's keystore... by app itself?" -- not unless there is a security flaw in Android.

Comment: well, the good practise would be to give a user chance to install one (the signing certificate) from inside the app, am i getting it right?